# Error: C compiler identification is unknown with Cmake 3.15.1 and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, build, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build project in Visual Studio 2019 environment with Cmake. But I'm getting following Error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\xyz\build>call "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools....\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"
>   x86_amd64
>
> ---
>
> ** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.2.3
>   ** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
>   ********************************************************************** [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_x64'
>   -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

I've included following lines in my execution to run the build,

```
call "%VS160COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
cmake ../xyz/ -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64
```

Following system environment variables are added to help the execution,

```
VCTargetsPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\

VS160COMNTOOLS: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools
```

Can some one explain me what could be a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to configure the project **without scripting**, just by typing appropriate commands?

Comment: Yes. Still facing the same issue. Even I have tried to make it work via cmake-gui, errors are still same.

Comment: Related post - [How to fix compiler identification unknown - Visual Studio 19](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59986555/465053)